# function that returns a string in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, console.log

I wrote a function that extracts the text of a web element.

```
getText(selector) { 
        let textValue;
        cy.get(selector).then(($value) => {
            textValue = $value.text()          // working
            return textValue;                 // not returning anything
        })
    }
```

How can I make `getText(selector)` return `textValue` ?

**Helper.js class**

```
class Helper {
       getText = (selector) => {
        return cy.get(selector).invoke('text')
            .then(text => {
                return text.trim()   // added to show a .then() step inside function
            })
    }
}
```

**StepDefs.js**

```
        Given("This is demo test", async function (string, string2) {
            const helper = new Helper()
            cy.visit("https://google.com");
                 
            // get Images link text
            let imageText;
            imageText = helpers.getText(':nth-child(2) > .gb_q').then(trimmedText => {
                expect(trimmedText).to.eql('Images'); // this assertion is passing
                return trimmedText 
            })

            //  imageText is not storing a string "Images", but an Object
            cy.task('log', imageText) // it prints [Object object]
    }
```

Comment: You can't. `cy.get` is asynchronous, you're just adding tasks to the queue not actually getting the value immediately. Read https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, too complex to understand for a beginner. I have mostly used java selenium

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, you can't directly assign from a `cy.get()`, you always need a `.then()` to extract the value.

The question might be, what is the best way?

Using a `Cypress.env()` is clunky and not necessary, you can just return the the `cy.get().then()` chain and use the returned parameter.

```js
const getText = (selector) => {
  return cy.get(selector).invoke('text')
    .then(text => {
      return text.trim()   // added to show a .then() step inside function
    })
}

...

getText(selector).then(trimmedText => {
  expect(trimmedText).to.eq('abc');       
})
```

---

It works the same as it would if there was no function wrapping the command chain, i.e equivalent to"

```js
cy.get(selector).invoke('text')
  .then(text => { return text.trim() })
  .then(trimmedText => {
    expect(trimmedText).to.eq('abc');       
  })
```

This is a good way to figure out how to extract certain commands into a function - the function call should be **logically equivalent to the commands inside the function**.

---

**Reproducible example using Helper class**

```js
class Helper {
  getText = (selector) => {
    return cy.get(selector).invoke('text')
     .then(text => {
       return text.trim()  
     })
  }
}

it('tests with Helper class', () => {
  
  cy.visit('http://example.com');
  
  const helper = new Helper()

  helper.getText('h1').then(trimmedText => {
    expect(trimmedText).to.eq('Example Domain')    // passes
  })

})
```

Comment: The return type is `[object Object]` not string. I have a `Helper.js` class where I wrote this method and then I am calling `helper.getText()` function in step definitions. I tried    `imageText = helper.getText(':nth-child(2) > .gb_q').then(trimmedText => {
        expect(trimmedText).to.eql('Hello World');
        return trimmedText
    })`

Comment: Helper.js class  `getText(selector) {
        return cy.get(selector).invoke('text')
            .then(text => { return text.trim() })
            .then(trimmedText => {
                // expect(trimmedText).to.eql('abc');
                this.sendLogs("Out getTextModAno for for the selector \"" + selector + "\"" + " is ")
            })
    }`

Comment: ***The return type is not string*** - Correct, as mentioned in comments and at the top of my answer, you cannot get a string returned. You must use a `.then()` to extract the string from the object.

Comment: Even after using `.then()` it is returning [Object object]. I have added what I tried in my question. Please check.

Comment: It works ok for me - have you mixed up `Helper` and `Helpers` ? Both are shown in your code.

Comment: No maybe a typo. I didn't

Comment: It's `eql` should be `eq` for comparing text. With that change, the code you posted works.

Comment: Can you share your code via gitHub or something? Because it is not working for me :(

Comment: I will add it to the answer...

Comment: Hey @Rab, that was not the expectation. Issue was storing the return value in variable `imageText` and using it further (may be for printing in console or other uses). So can you please post a solution where we can store returned string in global or class level variable?

Comment: Yeah, I think you are flogging a dead horse - it's been said multiple times that you can't do that. There's also a pile of questions asking the same thing, you can take the time to look at those answers to improve understanding.

Comment: Do you mean that we can't save an extracted value in a variable to reuse it further, in other functions? What a lame automation framework that would be.

Answer (score -1):

Your `return` only returns the value within the `cy.then()` command. Your function `getText()` does not return anything itself.

```js
const getText = (selector) => {
  return cy.get(selector).invoke('text');
}
```

However, that would return a variable of type `Chainable<String>`, and not simply `String`. You could use this in a separate Cypress chain to validate the text like so:

```
getText('foo').should('eq', 'bar');
```

Or, if you needed to access the variable outside of a Cypress chain, you could re-write the `getText()` function to store the value in a Cypress environment variable.

```js
const getText = (selector) => {
  return cy.get(selector).invoke('text').then((text) => {
    Cypress.env('textVal', text);
  });
}
...
getText('foo').then(() => {
  expect(Cypress.env('textVal')).to.eql('foo');
});
```

If storing the value in a Cypress environment variable, you'll want to make sure that you're handling the asynchronous nature of Cypress commands *in some way*, which I've done in the above example by only calling `Cypress.env()` once I'm within a `cy.then()` function